# Getting Values with Python from JSON Array with multiple entries

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a question regarding getting a specific value out of a JSON array based on a value that the array has. This might be a little vague bet let me show you.

I have a results array in JSON format:

```
{
    "result": [{
            "id": "SomeID1",
            "name": "NAME1"
        },
        {
            "id": "SomeID2",
            "name": "NAME2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I always know the name, but the ID is subject to change. So what  i want to do is get the ID value based on the name I give. I am not able to alter the JSON format as it is a result i get from an API call.

So when enter NAME1 the result should be "SomeID1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be (if name is unique):

```
data={
    "result": [{
            "id": "SomeID1",
            "name": "NAME1"
        },
        {
            "id": "SomeID2",
            "name": "NAME2"
        }
    ]
}

known_name ="NAME1"


print(next(x['id'] for x in data["result"] if x["name"]==known_name))
```

If name is not unique:

```
for x in data["result"]:
  if x['name'] == known_name:
    print(x["id"])
```

or you could store them in a list

```
print([x['id'] for x in data["result"] if x["name"]==known_name])
```